# Lync application crashing upon launching form other application on iOS8

Tags: ios

Trying to launch Lync application from my application using below code,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"lync://"]];
```

While testing my application on device, Lync app gets launched. It shows splash screen for 1 sec and then crashes.

This is tested on device having 
- Lync app version installed – Lync 2013
- iOS version tested – 8.1.3

Does any one know what could be issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I am a member of the Lync for iOS team.**

"lync://" is currently considered a malformed url.  You need to include an instruction with it as well.  Here is what we currently support:

- sip://xxxx@yyyy.com
- lync://confjoin?url=xxx

And will be included in an upcoming release:

- lync://call?id=xxxxx